# How to post galary image to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to post my gallery image to nodeJs server i am using the following code:-

```
  vm.getImageSaveContactInst = function() {       
  var options = {
      maximumImagesCount: 1, // Max number of selected images, I'm using only one for this example
      width: 800,
      height: 800,
      quality: 80            // Higher is better
  };
  $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options)
.then(function (results) {
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    vm.imageInst = /*"data:image/jpeg;base64,"*/ + results[i];
    vm.imageFinalInst = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + vm.imageInst
  }
}, function(error) {
  // error getting photos
});
};
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Then what is the issue? Did you define any route in node.js to get it?

Comment: Should i send  vm.imageFinalInst value to the node server?

Answer (score 0):

This solution served me the best:

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    var options1 = {
        maximumImagesCount: 1,
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        quality: 50
    };
    $scope.takeFromGallery = function () {
        $cordovaImagePicker.getPictures(options1)
            .then(function (results) {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(results.toString(),
                    function (fileEntry) {
                        function win(file) {
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                                $scope.registration.imgSrc = evt.target.result;    //this is your Base64 image  
                            };
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        };
                        var fail = function (evt) {};
                        fileEntry.file(win, fail);                           
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.log('error ' + error)
                    }
                );

            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16971644/6882135)

P.S.: Please don't forget to install and inject [Cordova File Plugin](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/)

Comment: Its crashing my gallery:(

Comment: But it shouldn't. You're doing something wrong. I've edited the post and provided my full code for you above.

Comment: Did you injected $cordovaFile into the controller? Could you please provide your code?

Comment: Thankx its working but having a little issue when the image size is high it makes a very Base64 string which i am not able to send to server.